# Error 403 (Forbidden) showing up when running GET for JSON (Wordpress API)

Tags: angularjs, json, wordpress

Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/0eHQPVRHmCWelK6VEYVE?p=preview

I'm trying to make an Analytics Chart using the JSON Data from my WordPress Site along with ChartJS. This is for an app being written in AngularJS.

But on localhost, I'm getting Error 403 while on Plunkr it reamains empty.

Please suggest a solution.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-json/llama/v1/stats').then(function(response) {
var visitDates = response.data.visits.labels.map(function(dateString) {
  return new Date(dateString);
});

$scope.visits = response.data.visits.datasets;
var dateData = [];
var countData = [], index = 0 , i;
angular.forEach($scope.visits, function(dataSet) {
  dataSet.data = dataSet.data.map(function(count, i) {
    index++;
    dateData[i] = visitDates[i];
    countData[i] = count;
    return {
      date: visitDates[i],
      count: count,
      dateData: dateData,
      countData: countData
    };
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 is permission issue on serverside.. It works well with plunker.

Here is the screenshot of the response and header and status = 200 ..
[image]

Data:

[image]

And the chart:
[image]

Comment: Then why am I not able to view the output and am getting the error?

Comment: Could you please add the logs or screen shot of error?

Comment: I do not get any such error.. and you code works pretty well... I guess you should even try in some other browser.. May be that might help.. Cuz there doesn't seem to be any error in you code.

Comment: Yes, I ran the code in another laptop and it works fine. Will have to research on this and run a fix for my machine now. Anyways, Thanks!